# Error Calling InitializeCache on WindowsAzure Storage Account

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I have the following snippet being called on on application start:

```
var driveCache = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("imageslive");
CloudDrive.InitializeCache(driveCache.RootPath, driveCache.MaximumSizeInMegabytes);
```

This has been working for year or so. I have just upload a new version of the site and am now getting the following error:

```
Exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudDrive.Interop.InteropCloudDriveException' was thrown.
at ThrowIfFailed(UInt32 hr)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudDrive.InitializeCache(String cachePath, Int32 totalCacheSize)

Unknown Error HRESULT=80070103
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudDrive.InitializeCache(String cachePath, Int32 totalCacheSize)
at Site.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

This works when running from within VS with the emulator so presumably is something about the update.

Does anyone have any pointers about how I might go about getting more information? I cannot see any way of getting more information, let alone what the sudden cause of the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been found to be a side effect of a security update in the latest Guest OS update.  The temporary solution is to modify your Cloud Service to use the March Guest OS (201503 versions --- 2.37, 3.25, or 4.18) instead of the Automatic Guest OS version.  You can find instructions for manually configuring the Guest OS version at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff729420.aspx.  We are investigating the issue in order to fix the root cause within the Guest OS itself so that you can continue using automatic Guest OS updates.

Also please note that the CloudDrive feature was never released out of beta.  With the upcoming storage service version retirement in December (http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/04/microsoft-azure-storage-service-version-removal/) the CloudDrive will no longer function.  You should begin making plans to migrate to Azure Files.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/07/24/migrating-data-to-microsoft-azure-files.aspx has information on how to migrate data.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the info. I will start looking at AzureFiles.